# What are people who 'flee' called?

Tags: single-word-requests

So as far as I understand 'to flee' is the verb, derivative noun from it is 'a flight' (as the process of running away), but what are the people who flee called? (And I don't mean cowards and other words of this kind.)

Comment: They’re flighty flying fleers.

Comment: While @JanusBahsJacquet's "fleers" works, kinda, I'd opt to change what (they) are called and use the more elegent "the (victims)(robbers)(elephants) fled...".

Comment: It seems to me that fly can also mean flee, so it may make sense to call them flyers.

Comment: @milestyle, sure, but nobody would really understand that they're fleeing - it would be assumed they were flying, right?

Comment: As a curiosity: the German word is _Flüchtling_, which in English would be _*flightling_

Comment: I've always been a fan of "fleedom"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Surely that would be ***fleet*** ones, for those who are not do not escape. :) *“The fleet have fled.”*

Comment: @tchrist, the fleet, flighty, flying fleers flew flailingly flom the flames of the flak?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Either that’s a new episode of *The Fugitive*, or of *Game of Thrones*.  Or both.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Despite how weird or unglamorous, the word you are looking for is actually **fleer**.  My dead-tree (thus not easily linkable) *American Heritage Dictionary* specifically lists it as a noun form at the end of its entry for *flee*.

Comment: Plus a note: I believe you pronounce this as "flee-er", it does not rhyme with "rear".

Comment: My dead-tree Webster's New Collegiate agrees.   Fleer also means "To laugh or grimace coarsely or scornfully; sneer; A word or look of derision or mockery."  Fleers aren't in a position to fleer until they have safely fled.

Answer (score 12):

Often 'refugee' may be a good noun to use when describing people who are fleeing.

Answer (score 12):

How about *fugitive*? Here is how [Encyclopédie Universelle](http://encyclopedie_universelle.fracademic.com/121912/fugitive) defines that term:

> a person who is fleeing, from prosecution, intolerable circumstances, etc.; a runaway: a fugitive from justice; a fugitive from a dictatorial regime.

Comment: "Fugitive" carries strong connotations of criminality.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could use *escapee*. Most nouns that mean to flee will carry strong connotations of something or another; it's just the nature of the game.

Answer (score 2):

What about *runner*?  The term is frequently used in popular media to identify one that flees.  The website [subzin](http://www.subzin.com/s/we%27ve+got+a+runner) lists at least 30 instances of the phrase “We have a runner.”

Answer (score 0):

Flee is synonymous with hasten, also a verb. It is derived from the Old French word 'haste' a noun which means: "Energetic speed in motion or action, as from eagerness, fear, urgency of circumstances, etc." From that a person who hastens(flees) is a (hastener). Source: The New Century Dictionary of the English Language, D.Appleton-Century Co., New York-London, 1944, p.717

Comment: Despite the fact that *flee* and *fleet* come form the same proto-Indo-European root, [*flee*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=flee) is from Old English, [*fleet*](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fleet) is from Old Norse, and *flee* hasn't meant *hasten* in English for well over 1000 years, if it ever did.

Answer (score 0):

> It may be, in yon smoke conceal'd,
>
> Your comrades chase e'en now the **fliers**,
>
> And, but for you,
> possess the field.

(A H Clough, 'Say not the struggle naught availeth')